# Cannot connect to remote server using VS Code - remote SSH extension

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have a problem when I try to connect to a remote server(linux) through vs code, using remote ssh extension.

Firstly, i can connect to the server in ssh when using the terminal, putty and even with the SSH FS extensions.

I have little permission in the server because is work environment(i can only edit folder and files in my user folder), and the server cannot download from external soruce, and only few ports are opened.

Logs( i hide ip,user and server disclaimer):

```
[14:36:38.747] Log Level: 2
[14:36:38.748] remote-ssh@0.76.1
[14:36:38.748] win32 x64
[14:36:38.749] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+<IPSERVER>", attempt 1
[14:36:38.750] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[14:36:38.750] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:36:38.750] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"<IPSERVER>":"linux","<IPSERVER>":"linux"}
[14:36:38.750] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[14:36:38.750] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[14:36:38.751] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[14:36:38.752] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": false
[14:36:38.752] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[14:36:38.752] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[14:36:38.752] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[14:36:38.757] SSH Resolver called for host: <IPSERVER>
[14:36:38.757] Setting up SSH remote "<IPSERVER>
[14:36:38.761] Using commit id "<longNumber>" and quality "stable" for server
[14:36:38.766] Install and start server if needed
[14:36:38.768] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[14:36:38.900] > OpenSSH_for_Win
[14:36:38.900] > dows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[14:36:38.908] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config"
[14:36:38.908] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true -F "C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config" "<IPSERVER>" bash
[14:36:38.913] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:36:39.265] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:36:39.266] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[14:36:39.356] > #
[14:36:39.376] > #########################################################################
<SERVER DISCLAIMER>

[14:36:39.707] > 13467ee179b9: running
[14:36:39.742] > Acquiring lock on /export/home/<USER>/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa2
> 09168452a3d97cc326/vscode-remote-lock.<USER>.f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d9
> 7cc326
> Found existing installation at /export/home/<USER>/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd
> 5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326...
> Checking /export/home/<USER>/.vscode-server/.f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d9
[14:36:39.745] > 
> 7cc326.log and /export/home/<USER>/.vscode-server/.f80445acd5a3dadef24aa2091684
> 52a3d97cc326.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 1909126
[14:36:39.756] > 
[14:36:39.772] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as <USER>ribed in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
[14:36:39.784] > 
> Checking server status on port 32829 with wget
> 13467ee179b9: start
> webUiAccessToken====
[14:36:39.793] > 
> listeningOn==32829==
> osReleaseId==rhel==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/54414==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> connectionToken==a1a1a1a1-111a-1111-111a-111a1aa1aaa1==
> 13467ee179b9: end
[14:36:39.794] Received install output: 
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==32829==
osReleaseId==rhel==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/54414==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
connectionToken==a1a1a1a1-111a-1111-111a-111a1aa1aaa1==

[14:36:39.794] Remote server is listening on 32829
[14:36:39.794] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":32829},"osReleaseId":"rhel","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/54414","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1a1a1a1-111a-1111-111a-111a1aa1aaa1"},"installUnpackCode":""}
[14:36:39.800] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config"
[14:36:39.800] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:61860:127.0.0.1:32829 -F "C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config" "<IPSERVER>" bash
[14:36:39.802] Spawning tunnel with: type "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-<IPSERVER>-155647009.sh" | ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:61860:127.0.0.1:32829 -F "C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config" "<IPSERVER>" bash
[14:36:39.802] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:36:39.803] > 
[14:36:40.038] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:36:40.143] > #
<SEVER DISCLAIMER>
[14:36:40.483] > Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
[14:36:40.484] Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 61860 and remote target 32829
[14:36:40.484] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[14:36:40.490] Tunneled 32829 to local port 61860
[14:36:40.490] Resolved "ssh-remote+<IPSERVER>" to "127.0.0.1:61860"
[14:36:40.500] ------




[14:36:40.731] > channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
[14:36:40.783] > channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
> channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
[14:36:41.112] "install" terminal command done
[14:36:41.113] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open You need to escalate this to your Linux administrators so that they can tune SSH server side settings to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

TCP Forwarding needs to be enabled for this feature to work. Other than asking the administrators to set `AllowTcpForwarding yes` on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, there is nothing you can do to make use of this feature. [Open issue - Don't rely on ssh TCP port forwarding](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/92).